# T-SQL: Variable Scope

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to store the results of an SQL query into a variable.The query simply detects the datatype of a column, hence the returned result is a single varchar.

```
SET @SQL = 
    'declare @@x varchar(max) SET @@x = (select DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE Table_name = ' +char(39)+@TabName+char(39) +
    ' AND column_name = ' +char(39)+@colName+char(39) + ')'
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Anything within the 'SET declaration' cannot access any variables outside of it and vice versa, so I am stuck on how to store the results of this query in a varchar variable to be accessed by other parts of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need a dynamic query to achieve what you want, below query will give the same result as yours.

```
  declare @x varchar(max)
  declare @tableName varchar(100), @ColumnName varchar(50)

  set @tableName = 'Employee'
  set @ColumnName = 'ID'

  select @x = DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  where
     Table_Name = @tableName
     and column_name = @ColumnName

  select @x
```

Comment: Your code worked fine, will just add that I used 'set @x = (select @x)' in order to store as a variable, thanks again

Answer (score 5):

All user-defined variables in T-SQL have private local-scope *only*.  They cannot be seen by any other execution context, not even nested ones (unlike #temp tables, which *can* be seen by nested scopes).  Using "*@@*" to try to trick it into making a global-variable doesn't work.

If you want to execute dynamic SQL and return information there are several ways to do it:

1. Use [sp_ExecuteSQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and make one of the parameters an `OUTPUT` parameter (recommended for single values).
2. Make a #Temp table before calling the dynamic SQL and then have the Dynamic SQL write to the same #Temp table (recommended for multiple values/rows).
3. Use the `INSERT..EXEC` statement to execute your dynamic SQL which returns its information as the output of a SELECT statement.  If the `INSERT` table has the same format as the dynamic SQL's `SELECT` output, then the data output will be inserted into your table.
4. If you want to return only an integer value, you can do this through the `RETURN` statement in dynamic SQL, and receive it via `@val = EXEC('...')`.
5. Use the Session context-info buffer (not recommended).

However, as others have pointed out, you shouldn't actually need dynamic SQL for what you are showing us here.  You can do just this with:

```
SET @x = ( SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE Table_name  = @TabName
              AND column_name = @colName )
```

Comment: Very Deatailed answer and an interesting read, I already marked another answer as complete prior to your response however. +1

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the sp_executesql stored procedure for dynamic sql.

The following link provides a good usage example of sp_executesql procedure with output parameters:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499

Comment: Thanks for the link, interesting read, added as a bookmark (Y)